# How to tell jQuery to do nothing

Tags: jquery, function

I have functions that apply to most of the li a-s and I want them not to apply on a certain few. How can I tell jQuery to not run any functions when clicking on links of my choice. jQuery.noop didn't do anything.

Comment: The normal idea of not running any code is to have no code whatsoever. But if you post your code we might be able to help you.

Comment: How about you downvote some more?
What I mean is, I have a function, that applies to all the links in a nav menu, but I wan't to remove that function from certain links, because I wan't to replace it with another function. If i just apply the new function to the same button, nothing works. And I can't just remove or edit that function, it isn't that flexible, I have been messing around with it for hours...

Comment: I didn't downvote you, just asking for some more information as of my reading the question was not clear. Now I see you got the question sorted, happy for you. But there are peolpe here at SO that is very fast on downvoting unclear questions. So prepare yourself for next time by adding simple code snippets for clearification, then you will probably not get downvoted.

Comment: All right, thanks for the tip :-)

Answer (score 5):

It's very hard to tell what you are asking, but I assume you have something like this:

```
$("a").on('click', function () { /* do something */ });
```

...but then when you click on `<a id="donothing">` you want it to do nothing.  You need more specific selectors, or you could individually do:

```
$("#donothing").off('click');
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use e.preventDefault(); or return false;

Answer (score 2):

i could use the .not() method and exclude the unwanted elements in the first place

```
$('li').not('#certian-link').on('click', function () { /* do something */ });
```

for detail see the jquery docs
http://api.jquery.com/not/

Comment: what if i had more than one ids?

Comment: @DivyeshJesadiya exclude by class e.g. .not('.certian-link') or use a list of id`s e.g. .not('#certian-link, #another-link, #yet-antoher-link')